# canvas.move(id, x, y) not working with arrow keys

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

The following code is from a book I am reading right now, but when it runs, the movement is only in one direction (leftward), no matter what arrow key is pressed:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import *
def mtri(event):
    if event.keysym == 'up':
        c.move(1, 0, -3)
    elif event.keysym == 'down':
        c.move(1, 0, 3)
    elif event.keysym == 'right':
        c.move(1, 3, 0)
    else: 
        c.move(1, -3, 0)
r = Tk()
c = Canvas(r, width=400, height=400)
c.pack()
c.create_polygon(10, 10, 10, 60, 50, 35)
#c.bind_all('<KeyPress-Up>', mtri)
#c.bind_all('<KeyPress-Down>', mtri)
#c.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', mtri)
#c.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', mtri)
c.bind_all('<Key>', mtri)
r.mainloop()
```

I'm confused about this, can someone help check if there is anything wrong in the code above?

Thanks!

Comment: The first thing you should do is verify that `event.keysym` is what you think it is. hint: it's not. Try printing out `event.keysym` at the very start of `mtri`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Nice suggestion. Sorry that I can't upvote your comment because my reputation is not above the threshold, yet. I tried your suggestion and now I see what `event.keysym` is in the printout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is fine the reason why it moving to the left only because none of the `if` conditions are true as `event.keysym` returns key word like "Up" , "Down", "Right" and so on, in which you can see the first letter is capital as compared to the code the `event.keysym == 'up'` they all are lower. **In short "Up" is not equals to "up" according to python.**

So by changing the *"up" , "down" , "right" **to** "Up" , "Down" , "Right"* respectively should solve the issue.

You can also check and compare the `event.keysym` by printing them to the console. Also one bind is fine `c.bind_all('<Key>', mtri)`.

Like so..

```
def mtri(event):
    print(event.keysym)
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        print('up')
        c.move(1, 0, -3)
    elif event.keysym == 'Down':
        print('down')
        c.move(1, 0, 3)
    elif event.keysym == 'Right':
        print('right')
        c.move(1, 3, 0)
    else: 
        print('left')
        c.move(1, -3, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the analysis and the suggestion. It's a shame that I didn't find the code in the book is `Up` instead of `up`. I checked it against the book twice and didn't find the discrepancy here. My bad. Also, just found it is kind of a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45872276/move-object-in-python-tkinter-canvas